# Prevent direct url access of pages by login

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to prevent direct access of pages without login CODEIGNITER?

I make this on [views > Nav]

It's working for preventing user when they wrong input their username.
But when I clicked home, it's success without password *sigh

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['username']==FALSE){
        redirect(base_url("usr/login"));
 }
?>
```

However I tried

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['username']||$_SESSION['password']==FALSE){
        redirect(base_url("usr/login"));
  }
?>
```

But the result

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main/home';
```

This pages sometimes comes to an error "has to many redirect loop" neither slow loading pages. And now it's preventing me from accessing homepage even with both username and password exist

Answer (score 0):

First Create a Model and add a construct

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if($_SESSION['username']==FALSE)
    {
        redirect(base_url("usr/login"));
    }
}
```

then

Call this model to your controller every time you want to check if the user is login

Comment: I don't want to use that on every model that I have. I was asking about how to make $_SESSION['password'] prevent will work.